# TextView timer seconds digits jumping

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have this code which simply displays a countdown clock to an event.  I am having an issue with it with regards to the last seconds place jumping digits unlike a normal clock.  Here is the code I am working with.  Could someone please offer some guidance to where this issue may be.  Kind regards.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File cfgFile = new File(sdcard, "TimeTillParis/config.txt");

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                try {
                    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(cfgFile);
                    Properties prop = new Properties();
                    prop.load(is);

                    int mmY = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("YEAR"));
                    int mmM = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("MONTH"));
                    int mmD = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("DAY"));
                    int mmH = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("HOUR"));
                    int mmC = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("MINUTE"));
                    int mmS = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("SECOND"));

                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Date today = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

                    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, mmY);
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mmM);
                    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mmD);
                    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mmH);
                    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mmC);
                    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, mmS);

                    long milliseconds = (cal.getTimeInMillis() - today.getTime());

                    String mD="", mH="", mM="", mS="", boxText="";

                    mD += (milliseconds / (1000*60*60*24));
                    mH += (milliseconds / (1000*60*60) % 24);
                    mM += (milliseconds / (1000*60) % 60);
                    mS += (milliseconds / 1000 % 60);

                    boxText += "Next visit to Paris in \n\n" +
                                mD + "d   " + 
                                mH + "h   " + 
                                mM + "m   " + 
                                mS + "s";

                    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_date_display);
                    textView.setText(boxText);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    String cfgNotFound="";
                    cfgNotFound += "config.txt not found!";
                    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_date_display);
                    textView.setText(cfgNotFound);
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 100);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepared complete solution, let me know if you have some questions:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int COUNTDOWN_INTERVAL = 1000;

    MyTimer timer;

    Calendar eventTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File cfgFile = new File(sdcard, "TimeTillParis/config.txt");

        try {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(cfgFile);
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(is);

            int mmY = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("YEAR"));
            int mmM = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("MONTH"));
            int mmD = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("DAY"));
            int mmH = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("HOUR"));
            int mmC = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("MINUTE"));
            int mmS = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("SECOND"));

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, mmY);
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mmM);
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mmD);
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mmH);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mmC);
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, mmS);

            eventTime = cal;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            String cfgNotFound="";
            cfgNotFound += "config.txt not found!";
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_date_display);
            textView.setText(cfgNotFound);
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(eventTime != null) {
            long millisInFuture = (eventTime.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis());
            timer = new MyTimer(this, millisInFuture, COUNTDOWN_INTERVAL);
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }

    private static class MyTimer extends CountDownTimer {

        TextView textView;

        public MyTimer(Activity actitivy, long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            // findViewById is very expansive, so fined it only once
            textView = (TextView) actitivy.findViewById(R.id.textView_date_display);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("'Next visit to Paris in \n\n'd'd   'h'h   'm'm   's's'");
            String boxText = sdf.format(new Date(millisUntilFinished));

            textView.setText(boxText);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working great.  There is just one problem with the calculation.  The date I have defined is for the 25th of April 2013 (I have the month defined as 3 in the config file), and the display is currently showing just 15d 1h 48m 14s when it should be around 45d 12h.  I've tried to fix it, but this is another thing I need to learn.

Comment: What about to save unix timestamp (miliseconds from 1970-01-01) to your file? IMHO montsh are counted from zero.

Comment: I have the correct days, hours and minutes displaying. I added the CEST timezone (just for testing) and also needed to subtract 1 month and also 1 day using cal.add().

Comment: Within SimpleDateFormat() i'm using DD for days.